# Python time module - clock_getres(clk_id),clock_gettime(clk_id), clock_settime(clk_id, time)

Tags: python, python-3.5

According to Python 3.5 documenation (time module) all three functions  `clock_getres(clk_id), clock_gettime(clk_id)` and `clock_settime(clk_id, time)` are available for Unix Systems. According to documentation:

> `clock_getres(clk_id)`  Return the resolution (precision) of the
>   specified clock `clk_id`
>
> `clock_gettime(clk_id)` Return the time of the specified  clock `clk_id`
>
> `clock_settime(clk_id, time)` Set the time of the specified clock
>   `clk_id`

But Python documenation doesn't say anything about `clk_id`.
Can someone explain me how to get `clk_id` using python.

Answer (score 1):

Basically clk_id it is integer id of clock, list of clock you can find at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html

for example **time.CLOCK_REALTIME** == 0 and **time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC** == 1, etc
for each clock you can set the time and surely time is different for every single one as well.

```
import time

clock_id_realtime = time.CLOCK_REALTIME
clock_id_monotonic = time.CLOCK_MONOTONIC
print('clock_id_realtime = %s' % clock_id_realtime)
print('clock_id_monotonic = %s' % clock_id_monotonic)

clock_realtime_time = time.clock_gettime(clock_id_realtime)
clock_monotonic_time = time.clock_gettime(clock_id_monotonic)

print('clock_realtime_time = %s' % clock_realtime_time)
print('clock_monotonic_time = %s' % clock_monotonic_time)

try:
    print(time.clock_settime(clock_id_realtime, clock_realtime_time))
except PermissionError:
    print('No permissions to change clock time')
```

Comment: So the variables from time modules like `time.CLOCK_REALTIME` etc. return the clock_ids. Thanks.